# WiX Launch Condition or Custom Action for Installed Application

Tags: wix, installation, conditional-statements, launch

I would like to set up my WiX installer to check for the existence of an existing application, as a condition to it being installed. If the pre-requisite application hasn't already been in installed on the target server, the installation should terminate.

Firstly, I am open to a solution that would be based on either (but not exclusively to) a Custom Action or a Launch Condition, although I must admit I'd perhaps lean more towards a launch condition as I find it much easier to use.

Secondly, due to the fact the ProductCode or GUID is the only attribute of the pre-requisite application that is recorded consistently in the Windows Registry of all servers where it's installed, my preference would be for a solution that is based around this property. In other words, I would prefer a launch condition or custom action that verifies that an application with the given ProductCode or GUID exists on the target server.

### Update

May I add the following points, as I'm still not sure whether my scenario is fully understood.

I have two separate products, which for sake of clarity I'll refer to as Product A and Product B. As a pre-requisite to installing Product B, Product A should already be installed on the target server. Can I reiterate that both products are installed from two different MSI installers and are completely unrelated.

Rick Bowerman, you make reference to the use of an Upgrade Id in your solution. Are you referring here to the Upgrade Id for Product A and is the code snippet you've produced to be inserted within the Product tag of Product B?

Finally, I'd really welcome some examples of any proposed solution if possible please.

Comment: It's not strictly true that the ProductCode is the only thing in the registry that you can use. Every component installed from that MSI can be located with a component search. All you need is a component guid from that product to use as a marker. See WiX ComponentSearch element. This is done in AppSearch so all you need is AppSearch before LaunchConditions, maybe the default anyway, and you're not stuck with relying on an upgrade search which will fail if there is a per user/per machine mismatch, so yes FindRelatedProducts needs to be early, but also you must have set ALLUSERS by then.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback PhilDW. However, I prefer basing my launch condition or custom action on a static value such as a Product ID, rather than a component or file GUID which could become redundant further down the line when for instance that component or file is no longer included in my MSI.

Comment: oh, then if the existing application is yours then you could add a registry item for the future for you to detect it. Then you're doing a registry search which is more reliable than relying on an upgrade search.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the GUID for Product A you can detect the version and then fail out if it is not detected in Product B. Add this after your Product tag in Product B.

```xml
<Upgrade Id ="Product A GUID">
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Minimum="0.0.0.0" 
                  Property="APPDETECTED" IncludeMinimum="yes" />
</Upgrade>
<Condition Message="Please Install Product A">
  <![CDATA[APPDETECTED OR Installed]]>
</Condition>
```

More and related information [here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/upgrades-and-modularization/checking-for-oldies).

Comment: Be sure to double check the scheduling of FindRelatedProducts when doing this.  It needs to go before LaunchConditions.

Comment: Rick Bowerman, thanks very much for your input. You make reference to the use of an Upgrade Id in your solution. Are you referring here to the Upgrade Id for Product A and is the code snippet you've produced to be inserted within the Product tag of Product B?

Comment: I'd really welcome some examples of any proposed solution if possible please. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer to be, hopefully, more clear, the code is to be inserted into Product B, it references the Product GUID/Code of Product A.